# Whole page shifts rigth when I change language

Tags: wordpress, layout

I have a wordpress website which was developed in english as a defualt wordpress language and it works great but as soon as I change the default wordpress language to Hebrew the whole page shift to right. It works fine when I switch back to english.Here is a screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uy-HsvnZFulijQ9KkI2gwcd5R96KTCld/view?usp=sharing

I have tried using CSS to fix it, disbaled all plugins and even changed the theme but the problem is still there and I can't fint any solution for it online.

Comment: What method are you using for the language management? WPML? Is this a website you can post a link to? Please provide more info.

Comment: I am not changing the content language, it is already in hebrew. I just changed the defualt language of wordpress to english for ease of development. Here is the website's link:
https://m-nadlan.com/

Comment: Ah in that case I can't really tell anything from the frontend... but it sounds like there's some issue with the RTL support and perhaps something getting translated that overflows. If you're able to edit the theme or apply custom CSS maybe try adding `overflow-x: hidden` to your `<html>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: I was using this on body tag but it wasn't working, I added it to the html tag and it resolved the issue. Thanks